# Has anyone found a good open source ajax calendar control (not a popup date picker)

Tags: open-source, calendar

We are looking at replacing a proprietary calendar control.   I've looked at scal [http://scal.fieldguidetoprogrammers.com](http://scal.fieldguidetoprogrammers.com/) but styling is weak and it's not functional enough for day-spanning events or concurrent events in the day view.  [Feyasoft.com](http://www.feyasoft.com) has a ExtJs based ajax calendar that looks great but its not open source.

Thanks in advance

**Update:** this question is looking for 'a view of calendar items like outlook web access would do', not a UI control for selecting a date.

Comment: feyasoft is now dual licensed using GPL v3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ripping out the calendar part of one of the open-source Ajaxy groupware projects, such as [Zimbra](http://zimbra.com), [Bongo](http://bongo-project.org), [Horde](http://horde.org) or [Zarafa](http://zarafa.com).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [DayPilot - Open-Source Outlook-Like Calendar/Scheduling Control for ASP.NET](http://www.daypilot.org/) will help you.

The open-source version of DayPilot (DayPilot Lite) does not have AJAX features, but features like day view, work week view, week view, highlighting of business hours, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are lots of date pickers -- I don't want a date picker at all.  Both the answers above are date picker controls.

I am looking for a ajax control that can render a view of calendar items like outlook web access would do (for example).

Comment: You should add this to the question.

Answer (score 2):

We use these guys: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar

It's free, open source and easy to implement - though you do need to implement data editing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Feyasoft.com](http://www.feyasoft.com/myCalendar) has a really great extjs based calendar application - seems recently they just made it as open source and downloadable. I just try it and seems it work well for me - look like google calendar. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We use the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [YUI Calendar Control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/) (from Yahoo)? It is open source and seems to have a lot of functionality. All of their controls are very well documented.

The questioner is asking for a full calendar, not just a date picker. The linked page says this:

> you may also find that the Calendar's
>   foundation classes are a good place to
>   start for more complex interfaces that
>   visually organize date-tagged
>   information (like appointments,
>   photos, events, etc.)

I am not aware of any full ajax calendars (like an open source Google Calendar), but it seems like this control might be a good place to start if you wanted to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

If a widget-based (web service) solution would work, you might consider InstantCal: http://instantcal.com

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with InstantCal

Answer (score 0):

use [www.web2cal.com](http://web2cal.com). It is the best for customization and creating ajax events calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: http://www.cubedrive.com/myCalendar

The best calendar open source I have seen, it has repeat type of events (daily, weekly, monthly, yearly etc) which are our needs.